# What is the proper visa for a Mexican citizen to work along with husband in the US?

Tags: usa, working-visas, marriage, mexican-citizens

I am a US citizen living with my Mexican wife in Mexico. We have no plans to live in the US, but much of my work is there. We would like to be able to legally work together in US, but work visas appear to be for specific jobs or for emigrating to US. Which type visa would be appropriate to allow us to work together on projects in US and allow us to remain in Mexico?

Comment: Depending on the nature of the projects, it may be permissible under a B-1 visa.  Can you give more information?

Answer (score 3):

There's no such visa. She can get a green card as your wife, but that requires actually moving to the US. There's no other immigration benefit your citizenship can get her.

Comment: But depending on the nature of the work, it may be allowed under a B-1 visa.

Comment: @phoog not because of the citizen-husband though, more likely despite him. This would generally work for short business trips, not staying for weeks or months at a time.

Comment: Projects are two to four days, max

Comment: @Ariadneflores you mentioned that you're electrician, and you expect your wife to fill in instead of the local helpers. It would be illegal to do that on B1/B2 visa, and if caught your wife may be deported and barred from entry to the US.